# I'm unable to store signUp data in the real-time database, it's storing authentication. but why it's not storing in real-time below is my code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to store signUp data in the real-time database, it's storing authentication. but why it's not storing in real-time below is my code.

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseDatabase database;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding= ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
    progressDialog.setMessage("We're creating your account");

    binding.btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressDialog.show();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.etEmail.getText().toString(), binding.etPassword.getText().toString()).
                    addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Users user = new Users(binding.etUserName.getText().toString() , binding.etEmail.getText().toString() ,
                                        binding.etPassword.getText().toString());


                                String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                                database.getReference().child("Users").child(id).push().setValue(user);

                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });

}
```

}

//in my firebase rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1627065000000",  // 2021-7-24
    ".write": "now < 1627065000000",  // 2021-7-24
    }
}
```

[I'm unable to store signUp data in the real-time database, it's storing authentication. but why it's not storing in real-time below is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sHnI.png)

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging yourself, to see what code actually executes. If you set breakpoints on each line, and run the code in a debugger: 1) does it reach `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and are the values what you expect? 2) does it reach the `onComplete` for that call, and if so: is the task successful? 3) If so, does it reach the call to `setValue` and are the values in there what you expect them to be? 4) If so, consider adding a completion listener there too as shown in https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: Please post the code in your `Users.java` file.

Comment: Please provide the info Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.